# Simplifying complex setf expressions

Tags: reference, macros, common-lisp

For rapid prototyping purposes in common-lisp it would be convenient to be able to easily function-modify an object in an arbitrary data structure. This would seem to involve calling an arbitrary function on a place in the data structure, replacing the object at that place with the result of the function call. Common-lisp has a number of specialized modification macros (eg, `incf`, `push`, `getf`, etc) for particular types of objects, and `setf` for generalized place modification (eg, `setf-second`, `setf-aref`, `setf-gethash`, etc). But rather than inventing new specialized macros for other object types, or having to mentally consider the characteristics of each macro (slowing down development), it might  be nice to have a generalized setf-like modification capability that was simpler to use than `setf`. For example, instead of `(setf (second (getf plist indicator)) (1+ (second (getf plist indicator))))` or `(incf (second (getf plist indicator)))`, one might write `(callf (second (getf plist indicator)) #'1+)`, using any of the normal one argument functions (or lambda-expression) provided by common-lisp or the user. Here is an attempt at code:

```
(defun call (object function) (funcall function object))
(define-modify-macro callf (&rest args) call)
```

Will something like this work for all general cases, and can it actually simplify code in practice?

Comment: Is [`DEFINE-MODIFY-MACRO`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_2.htm) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `callf`

I think what you are looking for is [`_f`](http://ep.yimg.com/ty/cdn/paulgraham/onlisp.lisp) from [OnLisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html) 12.4:

```
(defmacro _f (op place &rest args)
  "Modify place using `op`, e.g., (incf a) == (_f a 1+)"
  (multiple-value-bind (vars forms var set access)
      (get-setf-expansion place)
    `(let* (,@(mapcar #'list vars forms)
            (,(car var) (,op ,access ,@args)))
       ,set)))
```

This uses [`get-setf-expansion`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_get_se.htm) - the workhorse of [generalized reference](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/05_a.htm) handling.

Note that `_f` only works with [**single-value**](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/05_abc.htm) places.
IOW, `(_f (values a b c) 1+)` will **not** increment all 3 variables.
It is not all that hard to fix that though...

## can it actually simplify code in practice?

This **really** depends on your coding style and the specific problem you are solving.

Comment: That's it.  Great discussion in OnLisp too.